# Wifi not recognizing wireless networks in my area

Tags: wireless, disconnect

I'm trying a new post because the situation changed from my last one.

My wifi was not working at all a few days ago. After a suggestion was put forward, I attempted --reinstall linux-firmware and now have the following files:

```
ls /lib/firmware | grep 8000
iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
```

As you can see I am still missing the -22, -23, and -24.ucodes. The Wifi option appears on the network pane, and it shows up during rfkill list. But I cannot see any available wifi networks, and it says 'Wifi disconnected' under the top-right network panel.

```
rfkill list
 0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 3a
   serial: 44:85:00:62:8f:b8
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-26-generic firmware=34.0.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:127 memory:df200000-df201fff
```

'rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl' gives a very long line of code ending with:

```
 [3428.012482] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Scan failed! ret -110
```

My wifi worked in the 'test Ubuntu' part of setup before I fully installed the OS. I am running kernel 4.13. Please let me know if I can provide any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the absence of the -22, -23 and -24 firmware blobs is insignificant. As the driver is updated, the firmware is also updated. Not every firmware works with every driver version.

You are already loading the -34 firmware, a very new version.

There are some other steps that I suggest you might check. First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, here is a post that suggests that the -31 firmware might work better: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/51271 It is easy to try and easy to reverse if it isn’t helpful. We’ll rename the -34 so it doesn’t load and reboot so that the -31 loads and test:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo mv iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode iwlwifi-8000C-34.bak
```

Reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: Hey, this worked (mostly)! I can view all available wifi networks and  connect to most of the networks I've tried so far. The few remaining must have some sort of internal conflicting parameters. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour